# Lookup fields in a workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, office-365-developer

I'm having problems with lookupfields in a workflow in my Office365 Environment.

I have a list in a subsite, the lists name is Technical Document Names. I that list there is Three fields: Name, Full Name and Abbreviation.

I have made a custom site column that uses that list as a lookup, and exported / imported to the rootsite and now I'm using that column in a Content Type that I use in a couple of lists in other sites. I've checked all three columns in the configuration of the site column so I'm able so see the values of Name, Full Name and Abbreviation in my lists in the other sites, so the lookup is working as expected.

Now to the problem.

I'm trying to build a textstring that concatenates some values from the columns in the document libraries (like ID, Project and Abbreviation) in a workflow that is running on the lists.

If I choose "Name"-column from the lookupfield and returns the value as Lookupvalue in the string builder it works as expected, but when I tries to do the same thing with Abbreviation I only gets an error. I can see the column abbreviation in SharePoint Designers stringbuilder and I can choose it and the "Check for errors" is not complaining.

It seems like the thing I'm trying to accomplish is not supported, is there any workarounds?

What other techniques would be good? remote event receiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the additional columns are considered type Look-Up.  Try returning them in the workflow as just strings and see if you get the value.

Comment: Sorry to say this but I still just gets an error in the Workflow.

Comment: Sorry. My fault. There was Another error to that made the workflow fail.